# Weird behavior when trying to sort vectors in a list using a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, sorting, vector

I want to sort vectors in a list. I tried the following:

```
test <- list(c(2,3,1), c(3,2,1), c(1,2,3))
for (i in length(test)){
  test[[i]] <- sort(test[[i]])
}
test
```

Which returns the list unchanged (vectors not sorted):

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 1

[[2]]
[1] 3 2 1

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

However when I sort manually outside the loop the order is stored:

```
test[[1]]
```

```
[1] 2 3 1
```

```
test[[1]] <- sort(test[[1]])
test[[1]]
```

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

Why does the behaviour in the loop differ? I would expect the loop to store three vectors c(1,2,3) in the list. What am I missing?

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(test))`

Comment: Or simply do `lapply(test, sort)`

Answer (score -1):

I just figured the loop only loops over one element since `length(test) = 3`. Hence I should have used `for (i in 1:length(test))`.

Comment: `for (i in seq_along(test))` is slightly better